# Any way to prevent my advisor from destroying my publication?

Tags: advisor

My advisor said he will edit and submit my manuscript for me but the version he submit to the journal was full of mistakes that was not original in the manuscript that I send to him. Is there anyway that I can also be a corresponding author so I can monitor what he send to the journal? Just to clarify, I'm the first author on this.

Comment: _My advisor said he will edit and submit my manuscript for me_ — You should have refused.  It's unethical for _anyone_, advisor or otherwise, to submit a manuscript that lists you as a coauthor without your approval.  But by letting your advisor submit _for_ you, you've given him that approval.

Comment: Also: **Don't walk.  Run.**

Comment: @JeffE it sounds like the OP didn't have willingly let the advisor submit for him. I may misinterpret, but it seems to me that the advisor just submitted and said so afterwards. I certainly agree with your sentiment: [run, go, get to the chopper](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xs_OacEq2Sk).

Comment: I counted three grammatical errors in your first sentence, a fourth one in the question that followed, and a fifth one in a comment below, not counting the lower-case letter starting a sentence. Yesterday, someone had to do quite a bit of work to spruce up one of your [other questions](http://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/16237/revisions). Are you **sure** that maybe your paper doesn't need a little proofreading and editing?

Answer (score 8):

Sorry, my answer is a bit off-topic, but maybe still a good advice:

When I take a look at your recent postings, I would suggest you either

1. Talk to your advisor about *all* your concerns, in an undisturbed setting, maybe together with a third person both of you can trust.
2. Talk to his/her boss / dean of faculty, ... but be as objective as possible!
3. Look for an other advisor. When you opt for 3., you should reflect the whole situation and check, where you could have behaved differently in order to avoid similar situations in the future.
4. Quit academia.

The reason why I'm that off-topic is, under normal circumstances a paper submission by any co-author should be no problem and all authors have to agree on the submitted version of the paper. What you can do is retract the paper by contacting the editor of the journal. I would not do that if you opt for 1. (then your supervisor should contact the editor and tell he sent the wrong version of the paper and send a good one), but if you opt for 2.-3. you could do it.

Comment: When I look for other advisor, how should I explain all that's happening to me? Would they just think I'm bad-mouthing my advisor? should I let my advisor know if I look for other advisor? Thanks.

Comment: I suppose your advisor will not be surprised - tell him only you are considering it when you want to try option 1. The new advisor will be intersted in knowing why you quit. I'd suggest to tell there were severe problems which you prefer not to describe in detail because you don't want to talk badly about a former supervisor. If he insists, explain it very politely and reluctant. Explain, how you want to avoid such situations in the future.